# Div not getting displayed into 4 column and shrinking into 2 when adjusting window size

Tags: html, css

I have got a div which has 4 items and want to display them in a single row for large devices. It does display as I want, but there is a scroll bar on the page which makes this annoying. I need to scroll from left to right to see all the items if that makes sense.

Here's the code:

```css
.container {
        display: flex;
        width: 100%;
        height: 534px;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-device-width: 1080px) {
        .container {
          flex-direction: row;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          width: 100%;
        }
      }

      .item{
        width: 250px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 50px auto;
      }
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
 <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the height from the container if you want to remove the scroll bar.

Comment: Could you say a bit more about exactly what layouts you want? As the window size shrinks does it 'jump' to just two items on a line or at an intermediate size would you want 3 on a line? And for very narrow windows would you want to go to one on a line rather than have to scroll left/right?

Comment: I want 4 items in 1 row for desktop and 2 for mobile.

Comment: Think viewport rather than device-type - the user may set a narrow viewport on their desktop and some mobile devices are fairly wide. In any case device-width is now deprecated and may not work on some browsers now or in the future. Use max-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options depending on exactly what outcome you want.

The simplest is to just allow the items (which have a fixed width) to wrap to the next line when the window is too small to accommodate them all. This means you may sometimes get 3 on the first line and 1 on the second.

With more control you can switch to making sure there are either 4 or 2 (or, on really narrow windows, 1) item in a row.

This snippet uses a grid to do this with breakpoints set using max-width (see note below).

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  width: 100%;
  height: 534px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 270px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  }
}

.item {
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">1</div>
</div>
```

Note: `device-width` is deprecated (see for example [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width][1]

And the width of a device is not really relevant - what we need to adjust for is the width of the window. This is done in a media query with max-width.

Note also that both your original code and this snippet lessen the height of each item for narrower viewports as you have set a fixed height for the container. If you want the items to maintain full height then set height on the item (or adjust the height of container accordingly).
[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-width